# Highlight Substrings in a Vaadin Label

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I have a Vaadin label generated from user input. I would like to validate the content of the area and, in the event of an error, highlight the substring of text where the error occurs. I know labels support html content, so something like

```
Label example = new Label("Foo <span>Bar</span>", ContentMode.HTML);
```

with some css could highlight Bar in the label. This works fine for highlighting one substring, but gets difficult to manage when highlighting multiple parts of the label or attempting to highlight in different colors.

Does anyone know of an add-on to assist with this?

Thank you,

Oliver

Comment: I don't know of such a add on. But just extend the Label in your new class and assign the `<span>` tags a class which represents your colors/styles

Comment: I would strongly advise against using `ContentMode.HTML` for displaying user input. You'd open up your application for Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such an add-on either, but you could do something like this:

`Label example = new Label("Foo <span class=field1>Bar1</span><span class=field2>Bar2</span>", ContentMode.HTML);`

Then in your style sheet you write:

```
.error1 .field1 {
    color: red;
}

.error2 .field2 {
    color: red;
}
```

Then if you have an error in part 1 of your label you do:

`label.addStyleName("error1");`

And vice versa for part 2 of the label. This should mark the part in the label red.